# Is there a way to check if a $_POST exists?

Tags: php, post

I am repeatedly calling the same page to perform the same action an x amount of times. In the page before this loop, I have a form asking for input. Only the first time when the loop runs I want to use the given value, but when I have the `$_POST` in the code, it gives an error.

So I have two questions:

1. Does PHP go on with executing the code when 'erroring', if not, is there a way to let it do so, because that would solve my problem.
2. Can I skip a piece of the code? Something like `skip lines 12-14` or something...

I could post my code, but I don't think that will make much sense, since I have some other pages too and txt files and such and if you don't know what it is for, it is rather hard to understand.

I will summarize though:

page1.html:

```
<form action="page2.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="input">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

page2.php:

```
for($i = 0; $i < $_POST['text']; $i++){
print "<form action=\"page2.php\" method=\"post\">";
}
```

As you can see, the loop calls `page2.php` again, but the `$_POST['text']` will not exist anymore. So, is there a way to go around this?

I have tried this:

```
if($another_counter_from_another_page > 1){
//Do nothing
}
else
{
$_SESSION['counter']=$_POST['text'];
}
```

And then replace the `$_POST['text']` in the `for`-loop with `$_SESSION['counter']`, but I still get an error even when `$another_counter_from_another_page > 1` is true, so that is why I asked for a way to skip a piece of code.

Thank you in advance, I hope my problem is clear from the example I gave...

Comment: Use the `isset()` function.

Comment: use isset() to check if $_POST is not null

Comment: @Mr.coder I think `$_POST` is never null.

Comment: You can use `isset()` and `is_empty()` together

Comment: Thank you! The `isset()` function got me rid of the error!

Comment: @ikhebgeenaccount you can never know but its still a good practise to use isset() or !empty() to check is a value was submitted

Comment: PHP does what you program with it. 1.) is possible therefore in both ways: So that PHP does stop or does continue when you detect an error in your form data. You're in control, you decide. 2.) Yes, you can do so. Search for PHP and conditions/control structures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a single key:

```
 if(isset($_POST['myKey'])) {
     echo "myKey exists"
 }
```

If you want to know if there is any POST data:

```
if(!empty($_POST)) {
    echo "We have POST data"
}
```